# I need to renew the value of n here everytime

Tags: java

The value of "n" has to change when it returns to the main method from the number method, this is how i used to do it in javascript, i also used to assign a variable to the output, can anyone tell me how to proceed here?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

 public class Solution {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();

    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
       int n = in.nextInt();
       int temp1=0;
       int count=0;
       int temp2=0;
       boolean y=false;

       int temp;
        String op="";
        String op1="";
        String op2="";

  temp=n;

  if ((n%3)==0){
      for (int a = 0; a < n; a++){
          op=op+"5";
      }
     System.out.println(op);
  }  

            if ((n%3)!=0){
           // System.out.println(n);   
            number(n,y,count,temp1);
           // System.out.println(temp);
            if ((temp-n)%3==0){
             for (int a1 = 1; a1 <= (temp-n); a1++)   
                {op1=op1+"5";}
            } 

            if ((n!=0)&&(n%5==0)){
                for (int a2 = 1; a2 <= n; a2++)   
                {op2=op2+"3";}
            }
                op=op1+op2;



                if (op==""){System.out.println("-1");}
                else
                {System.out.println(op);
                }
      }

       }
   }
         public static int number(int n, boolean y, int count,int temp1) {
           boolean x=false;
           int no=0;
               int ni=0;
           if (count==0) {temp1=n;}
           count=count+1;
           for (int a3 = n-1; a3 >=1 ; a3--) {
               if ((a3%3)==0 ){
                   no=a3;
                   x=true;
                   break;
               }
           }
          if (x==true){
              if ((no%5==0)||(temp1-no)%5==0){
                  if (no%5==0){
                      y=true;
                      n=no;
                  }
                  if ((temp1-no)%5==0){
                      y=true;
                      n=(temp1-no);
                  }

              }
              else{

                  n=no;
                 // System.out.println(n);
                  number(n,y,count,temp1);
                  }
          }     
            if (y==false){
               n=temp1;
            }
               return n;
            }
           }
```

Comment: `n = number(n,y,count,temp1);` - you need to use the return value from `number`.

Comment: Please follow this guide when asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This question is too specific.

Answer (score 1):

In your code assign the return value of `number(n,y,count,temp1);` to `n` as below, the `n` can be refreshed every time;

`n = number(n,y,count,temp1);`

Comment: even on doing so, the value remains as n , the same value i passed into the function